# Replace vector in dot product

Tags: linear-algebra

Hello I have a question related to the dot product. Say I have a dot product
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b}
\end{equation}
now I want to replace $\mathbf{b}$ with $\mathbf{c}$, but I only know
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{b} \cdot \mathbf{c} = \vert b \vert \vert c \vert \cos(\beta) \, .
\end{equation}
What can I do (to solve for $\mathbf{b} = \dots \mathbf{c}$) with this, to find an expression for
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{c} 
\end{equation}

Comment: You did not provide enough information. What are **all** the quantities that you know?

Comment: I consider arbitrary vectors $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$, so $\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b} = \vert a \vert \vert b \vert \cos(\alpha)$. Now I want to replace $\mathbf{b}$ with an arbitrary vector $\mathbf{c}$. I want to find an expression for $\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{c}$ that includes all options, i.e. all possible angles between $\mathbf{b}$ and $\mathbf{c}$...(in the problem I have in mind $\mathbf{b}$ and $\mathbf{c}$ are both velocities and I want to find an interpretation what it means to consider velocity $\mathbf{c}$ instead of velocity $\mathbf{b}$)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem cannot be solved. Say you are given the vectors $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$, and for vector $\mathbf{c}$ you are given both magnitude and the angle with respect to $\mathbf{b}$. You should draw the first two vectors. To draw the third one you start from the origin, and the tip of the vector is on a circle around vector $\mathbf{b}$, such as that $\mathbf{c}$ will cover a cone with the half angle given by the angle between $\mathbf{b}$ and $\mathbf{c}$. That means that the angle between $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{c}$ can be any number between $\angle \mathbf{a}\mathbf{b}-\angle \mathbf{c}\mathbf{b}$ and $\angle \mathbf{a}\mathbf{b}+\angle \mathbf{c}\mathbf{b}$. There might be some modulos in the above expression. For example, if $\mathbf{a}$ is perpendicular to $\mathbf{b}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ makes a $45^\circ$ angle with $\mathbf{c}$, the angle between $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{c}$ can be anything between $45^\circ$ and $135^\circ$, including $90^\circ$. So there is no way to write the dot product with the information given.